# UK Immigration and EU and Non EU Passport Couple

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration

We are a same sex married couple, my husband has a Singaporean passport and I have an EU/UK passport... Can he join me in the EU line at immigration when we visit in September ? The last time we visited the UK it took 4 hours for him to go through and we do not want the same thing to happen again

Comment: First things first: are you and yours visiting? Or exercising treaty rights? or some other thing?  And by EU/UK passport it means you are British?

Comment: I'm a British Citizen and my wife is Indian. When we fly into UK airports we can choose either the "UK/EU" queue or the "Non-EU" queue - depending on which one is shorter! At some terminals (e.g. Heathrow T5) UK/EU citizens are now mostly directed through the electronic gates. There is however a separate queue for families with small children and those who don't yet have passports which can be read by these gates. You may be directed to this queue.

Comment: `Can he join me in the EU line at immigration` When I last landed at Heathrow, I saw people with your problem at the EU queues and the border officer was processing them just fine.